# Lift framework: Boot.scala is not being executed

Tags: scala, lift, boot

I am starting to write a simple Lift application.

I'm running into a problem that `Boot` does not seem to run.
Nither does my `println("starting")` print, nor my debugger trip at the debugger point.

I am following the [cookbook](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000030/ch01.html#_solution_2) to the word.

Answer (score 0):

By debugging around in the source code of Lift, I found this block of code:

```
private[http] case object DefaultBootstrap extends Bootable {
def boot(): Unit = {
  val f = createInvoker("boot", Class.forName("bootstrap.liftweb.Boot").newInstance.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
  f.map {f => f()}
  }
}
```

Basically, if the boot class is not configured inside `web.xml`, Lift defaults to `bootstrap.liftweb.Boot` as the boot class.

However in the cookbook it states:

> Finally, set up the basic Lift boot settings by creating a Boot.scala file at src/main/scala/**bootstrap/Boot**.scala.

I solved my problem by placing `Boot.scala` into `src/scala/main/bootstrap/liftweb` directory